# Why the footer element has a wrong position when removing the property "position:relative" of its parent wrapper element

Tags: html, css

I try to make a html page with footer element always at bottom, and I followed this [article](http://cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/) and everything works perfectly.

But I found that if I remove the property "position:relative" from the CSS class "wrapper", the footer will have a wrong position as shown in the following image.

Because I am not very familiar with CSS, I wonder why "position:relative" is required in this situation.

[source - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLgzf3pw/)

CSS:

```css
html,
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
 min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
 background:#ededed;
 padding:10px;
}
#content {
 padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
 background:#ffab62;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
  </div><!-- #header -->
  <div id="content">
            <script>
                for (var i=0; i<=100; i++) {
                    document.write("<p>line " + i + "</p>");
                }
            </script>
  </div><!-- #content -->
  <div id="footer">
  </div><!-- #footer -->
</div><!-- #wrapper -->
```

[image: The position of footer is in the middle of the page rather than bottom]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the property `position` of `#footer` is `absolute`.

Which means that, it will have an absolute position regarding to **the first parent that will have a relative position** (in this case `<div id="wrapper">` )

If no parent has this property, it will be absolute regarding to `body`

Comment: "the first parent that will have a relative position", thanks a lot!

Comment: To be more precisely, I think it would be "the first parent with a positioned property(except static)". See [W3CSchool](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). As a result, position "absolute" and "fixed" will work too, though "relative" is a more reasonable answer.